# How to add checkboxes values of different names to the URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have check boxes with different names under different side-menus but having same name under each side-menu. Example:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="second[]" value="<?php echo $i + 10;?>" id="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i+10;?><br>
<?php } 

    for($j=123; $j<=129; $j++){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="third[]" value="<?php echo $j+10;?>" id="<?php echo $j;?>"><?php echo $j+10;?><br>
    <?php } ?>

    for($k=223; $k<=259; $k++){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fourth[]" value="<?php echo $k + 10;?>" id="<?php echo $k;?>"><?php echo $k+10;?><br>
    <?php } ?>
```

I want to get the values of the checked check boxes in the URL in the form of string with their values printed after their respective name when once checked.

URL should be like: http://something.com/?name1=value1+value2+value3&name2=value1(of second name)+value2+value3&name3=and so on...

**Whenever a checkbox is clicked with a different name its value must be added in the string after its corresponding name only in the URL.
Have to code this using Javascript/JQuery and can use bit of PHP also in JS.** Thanks

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML and JavaScript and leave out the PHP since it is not relevant. If you name them name1[] and name2][], they will show as arrays in PHP

Comment: show you browser rendered html .

Comment: Set the name for checkbox that can have multiple values to end with `[]`. e.g `<input name="third[]" ...>`

Comment: That URL structure makes no sense. What is your use case? Explain higher level problem also

Comment: may i know what your going do with this type  url query string ?

Comment: In the left panel when you click certain check boxes, you will notice the URL being changed. I want somewhat that kind of URL. Kindly refer to this link: http://www.quikr.com/jobs/jobs-lucknow+zwqxj2726005330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the input name for checkboxes that can have multiple values so that they can be selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#choiceForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = {}, regularizedParams = {}, allParams = [], allParamString;
    
    $(this).find("input")
            .each(function(i, el) {
            
              if (el.checked == true) {
                if (!params[el.name]) params[el.name] = [el.value];

                else params[el.name].push(el.value);
              }
            });

    for (key in params) regularizedParams[key.slice(0, -2)] = params[key].join('+');
 
    
    for (key in regularizedParams) allParams.push([key, regularizedParams[key]].join('='));
      
    allParamsString = allParams.join('&');
    console.log(allParamsString); // chuck this into your URL
    
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form id="choiceForm">
  <input name="iceCream[]" type="checkbox" value="vanilla"> Vanilla
  <input name="iceCream[]" type="checkbox" value="chocolate"> Chocolate
  <input name="iceCream[]" type="checkbox" value="strawberry"> Strawberry
  <button type="submit">Choose icecream flavor</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```